# PowerShell HTTPS GET using client certificate from certstore

Tags: powershell, https, get, certificate

I'm trying find easy way how check web content via HTTPS with using client certificate.
I have VBScript where is defined Client certificate, skipped Server certificate and defined what I'm searching (string "running"). My point is rewrite script to PowerShell.

Here is VBScode:

```
device = "10.10.10.10"
link = "5001/test"
Set Http = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
Http.SetClientCertificate "LOCAL_MACHINE\MY\test"
Http.Option(4) = 256 + 512 + 4096 + 8192 
Http.Open "GET", "https://" & device & ":" & link, false
Http.Send
output = Http.ResponseText
If InStr(1,output,"running") Then
wscript.echo "OK"
Else
wscript.echo "Error"
End If
Set Http = Nothing
```

Here is Powershell syntax to get HTTP web content (but not https):

```
$page = (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://10.10.10.10:5001/test")
"$page"
```

Here is Powershell syntax to get HTTPS contetn using .CRT file (but not from CERTSTORE)

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::CreateFromCertFile("C:\Cert\test.crt")
$url = "https://10.10.10.10:5001/test"
$web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$web.ClientCertificates.Add($Cert)
```

Here is my latest try to get web contetn. No success.

```
#ignore untrusted certificate
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
#load my client certificate defined by thumbprint
$cert = Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\My\5AA55B7B8D99
#get web contetn
$web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
#use my client certificate
$web.ClientCertificates.Add($Cert)
```

Any ideas ?
Best regards

Comment: You can not use a CRT file for HTTPS client auth. It only contains a certificate but not the private key.

Comment: Yes,so that is reason to use certstore.

Comment: So i have script down bellow but still not work. Any idea? Best regards

Comment: `#ignore untrusted certificate`  
`[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}`  
`#load my client certificate defined by thumbprint`  
`$cert = Get-Childitem cert:\LocalMachine\My\5AA55B7B8D99`
`#get web contetn`
`$web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)`
`#use my client certificate`
`$web.ClientCertificates.Add($Cert)`

Comment: You should not use comment section for adding new information. Edit your question instead - that improves readability of code a lot.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
Invoke-RestMethod https://10.10.10.10:5001/test -CertificateThumbprint XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, it wouldn't accept the thumbprint despite the cert being in my personal store.

Comment: Is this safe enough?

Comment: It seems the reason this might fail is that only the CurrentUser store is searched, as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598365/how-to-access-a-certifciate-with-error-unable-to-retrieve-certificates-because . James' answer below retrieving the certificate first worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Bit of a late answer but this is what I ended up with after reading the current answers.

You can use "Invoke-WebRequest" and the -Certificate parameter. You can also use "wget" in Powershell as it is the alias for "Invoke-WebRequest"

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\LocalMachine\My\5AA55B7B8D99
$response = wget -Uri "https://10.10.10.10:5001/test" -method "Get" -Certificate $cert
$response.Content.Contains("running")
```

Comment: Get-Item is interchangeable with Get-ChildItem in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me when I was trying to create a client certificate enabled sensor for PRTG. You might want to change the timeout value. Also you'll want to trap exceptions in case the site is unreachable for whatever reason.

*$CertNumber* = thumbprint of certificate.

*$CheckURL* = URL to load.

**CERTIFICATE LOADING AND READING SITE**

```
#*************************************
#********CERTIFICATE LOADING**********
#*************************************

# LOAD CERTIFICATE FROM STORE
$Certificate = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$CertNumber
# CREATE WEB REQUEST
$req = [system.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create($checkURL)
# ADD CERTS TO WEB REQUEST
$req.ClientCertificates.AddRange($Certificate)

#*************************************
#***********READING SITE**************
#*************************************

#SET TIMEOUT 
$req.Timeout=10000
# GET WEB RESPONSE
$res = $req.GetResponse()
# GET DATA FROM RESPONSE
$ResponseStream = $res.GetResponseStream()
# Create a stream reader and read the stream returning the string value.
$StreamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList $ResponseStream
# BUILD STRING FROM RESPONSE
$strHtml = $StreamReader.ReadToEnd()
```

Answer (score 1):

One issue might be that the client machine has to trust the certificate that it's sending. So if the client cert you're trying to send is not self-signed, then the issuer cert needs to be imported into the trusted root of the machine. Once you have that, you can use the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2` constructor (rather than `CreateFromCertFile` method) to add `MachineKeySet` flag

For example, on my machine, I have a pfx (with no password, hence the `$null` for the 2nd argument) and I want to POST some content that requires client cert auth:

`[Powershell]`

```
$content = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("SomeContentIWantToPOST.json")
$endpoint = "https://contoso.com/endpoint"
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2("MySuperPrivateCert.pfx",$null,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::MachineKeySet)
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($endpoint)
$request.ClientCertificates.Add($Cert)
$request.Method = "POST"
$request.ContentLength = $content.Length
$request.ContentType = "application/json"
$dataStream = $request.GetRequestStream()
$dataStream.Write($content, 0, $content.Length)
$dataStream.Close()
```

Answer (score -1):

Thy this, but I can't test it

```
$device = "10.10.10.10"
$link = "5001/test"
$Http = New-Object 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1'
$Http.SetClientCertificate( "LOCAL_MACHINE\MY\test" )
$Http.Option(256 + 512 + 4096 + 8192) # or $Http.Option(4)
$Http.Open("GET", "https://" + $device + ":" + $link, $false)
Http.Send()
$output = Http.ResponseText
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest accessing certificates using .NET class [X509Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx). Using [Certificates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.certificates(v=vs.110).aspx) property (example below) you can find certificate by thumbprint and attach it to the request.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$Store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store(
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]::My, "localmachine")
$Store.Open("MaxAllowed")
$Certificate = $Store.Certificates |  Where-Object Thumbprint -Eq "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$Web = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($Url)
$Web.ClientCertificates.Add($Certificate)
$Response = $Web.GetResponse()
```

Comment: I'd recommend posting an answer that consists of more than just a code block. Perhaps users will learn more if you explain your solution?