# How to access a certifciate with error: "Unable to retrieve certificates because the thumbprint is not valid"

Tags: powershell, permissions, certificate, certificate-store

I'm getting the error

> Unable to retrieve certificates because the thumbprint is not valid.
> Verify the thumbprint and retry.

when I try to use a certificate in the LocalMachine certificate store.

I've had an admin account install the certificate (including the private key) in the *LocalMachine* certificate store, and have provided access to the private key for certain users (e.g. functional ID).

I expected to be able to run the following code to get the thumbprint, which is then used in the `Invoke-WebRequest` call:

```
$certStorePath  = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$certDetails    = Get-ChildItem -Path $certStorePath | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "*myCert*"}   # Returns one result
$certThumbprint = $certDetails.Thumbprint

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $externalUrl -Proxy $proxyServer -UseBasicParsing -CertificateThumbprint $certThumbprint
```

I can get the cert details including thumbprint ($certDetails), but seems like permissions aren't allowing me (or the FID) to *use* the certificate (or perhaps just access the private key part of the certificate). The code works when the certificate is installed in the *CurrentUser* store.

How can I enable access to the certificate in the *LocalMachine* store for such non-admin users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that the problem is linked to `Invoke-WebRequest` and how it's used in this piece of code.

The first part of the code is able to access the certificate successfully:

```bsh
$certStorePath  = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$certDetails    = Get-ChildItem -Path $certStorePath | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "*myCert*"}
```

However, although the thumbprint is unique in across all certificate stores (e.g. this one only exists in LocalMachine), `Invoke-WebRequest` cannot access it, because *it* will only look in the CurrentUser certificate store.

So, overall to get this working:

1. Install the certificate which includes the private key.
2. Provide access to the private key part of the certificate, to the appropriate users/FID.
3. Use `Get-ChildItem` to get the certificate itself, and pass *that* to `Invoke-WebRequest` instead of a thumbprint:

```bsh
$certStorePath = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My"
$certificate   = Get-ChildItem -Path $certStorePath | Where-Object {$_.Subject -like "*myCert*"}   # Returns one result

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $externalUrl -Proxy $proxyServer -UseBasicParsing -Certificate $certificate
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slight alternative to Mark-DG1's correct solution:

Open powershell as SYSTEM. You can use SysInternal's psexec (still works well from what I can tell), Task Scheduler, or grab Invoke-CommandAs from [PSGallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Invoke-CommandAs/3.1.6)

```
psexec -s -i powershell
```

Then from the ensuing prompt, you find your *$certificate* like above, or you can directly reference the thumbprint (for a cert in the computer account personal store):

```
$certificate = gi Cert:\LocalMachine\My\*<certificate thumbprint>*

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "<targetURL>" [-Proxy $proxyServer] -UseBasicParsing -Certificate $certificate
```